# inv edit for minecraft 1.19

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want a inv editor for minecraft 1.19 because on my server someone has a  item in there inv that when they join they get kicked for nbt related reason about inv
can anyone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## If you use a ***server***

### Method 1 : Server’s Console

| # |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Go to your server’s console |
| 2 | `/clear <name>` |

**NOTE:** Might not work

### Method 2 : Command Block

| # |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Join the server |
| 2 | `/give @s minecraft:repeating_command_block` |
| 3 | Right-Click the command block |
| 4 | In the command block, enter this command: |
|  | `/clear <name>` |

## If you use a ***LAN world***

### Method 1 : NBT editor

I suggest using Universal Minecraft Editors, here are the steps

- Open Univertial Minecraft Editor
- Select “Java Edition”
- Open the world
- Go to “players”
- Find the player
- Double-click the player
- Find the item and delete it

### Method 2 : Command Block

| # |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Join the world |
| 2 | `/give @s minecraft:repeating_command_block` |
| 3 | Right-Click the command block |
| 4 | In the command block, enter this command: |
|  | `/clear <name>` |